# onelogin API List Connectors from Office 365

Tags: javascript, api, onelogin

I am looking at the API https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/connectors/list-connectors and I am trying to get the list of connectors to return in a rest call while in SharePoint Online.

**Is this even possible?**

If so does anyone have a javascript example of how they are returning any object?

I just need something or just know it is not possible.

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

Certainly possible from the Onelogin side. The SharePoint side also looks fine.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211546/calling-external-secure-rest-apis-from-a-sharepoint-form

Comment: I'm sorry, how does this answer my question?

I can do REST calls all day long, within SharePoint.

My issue is I can not get data from OneLogin while in a SharePoint session.

OneLogin is the authentication provider, os I should not be authenticating to OneLoing, they already have a token.

I really am looking for a working example.  Not a post that does not link to OneLogin, SharePoint works great. ;)

Comment: Your question was extremely vague and asked whether it was possible. I replied that it was possible, which direcly answers your question. If you can do REST calls "all day long" then I don't understand your issue. "I can not get data from OneLogin while in a SharePoint session". Why is that ? The API tells you exactly how to do it.